# everytime i try to import flask from flask it shows import error. What should i do?

Tags: python, flask, import, runtime-error

I typed "from flask import flask" in my python shell. it is now showing import error "cannot import name flask from flask".

Comment: Have you *installed* Flask with `pip install flask`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOveflow, Please add the output of `pip freeze | grep flask` and let us know, are u using `Virtual Environment` ?

Answer (score 6):

It is just title case needs to be Capital letter. try this

```
from flask import Flask
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `Flask` with:

```
pip install Flask
```